# How to reuse AWS socket?

Tags: websocket, ada

I am using an [AWS webserver](https://docs.adacore.com/aws-docs/aws/using_aws.html), which is being polled by some other script. The problem is that when I start the server twice in a few seconds (with requests of a client in between), the server fails to start again, saying:

```
raised AWS.NET.SOCKET_ERROR : Bind : [98] Address already in use
```

There is [this old thread](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flists.adacore.com%2Fpipermail%2Faws%2F2008%2DJune%2F000899.html) that suggests there may be a reuse_address
option, either in a ini file or as a direct parameter, but says that that also does not work.

Perhaps there is some way to force the OS to abandon the socket?

Comment: I assume you need to call `AWS.Config.Set.Reuse_Address (Config, True);`, but then again, I don't use AWS yet and I'm only scanning the sources.

Comment: _Perhaps there is some way to force the OS to abandon the socket?_ Yes, but it depends on the OS, for [example](https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait).

Comment: @Bib You were right, that works! Please post it as answer, I can edit it to add the details and complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `AWS.Config.Set.Reuse_Address (Config, True);` or set it in [the AWS ini file](https://docs.adacore.com/aws-docs/aws/using_aws.html#configuration-options).

For example:

```
with AWS.Config;
with AWS.Config.Set;
(...)
declare
   HTTP_Server : AWS.Server.HTTP;
   AWS_Config      : AWS.Config.Object := AWS.Config.Default_Config;
begin
   AWS.Config.Set.Reuse_Address (AWS_Config, True);
   AWS.Config.Set.Server_Port (AWS_Config, 80);
   AWS.Server.Start (HTTP_Server, Callback => Respond'Unrestricted_Access, Config => AWS_Config);
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! [My commit fixing my case in AdaBots](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/AdaBots/commit/225a9b51a4eab14f908d342be3a161810d11366b) may also help future readers.